# RIP Ray Stevenson, actor in Thor, Rome, Punisher: War Zone

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Actor Ray Stevenson passed away recently at the tragically young age of 58. Since his breakout role in 2004's *King Arthur*, Stevenson had been a genre mainstay, playing supporting roles in *G.I. Joe: Retaliation*, the *Thor* series, the *Divergent* series, and *The Book of Eli*. He also lent his voice to *Star Wars Rebels* and *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* and will play a pivotal role in the upcoming series *Ahsoka*. He is perhaps best known for his portrayal of the Punisher in the criminally underrated *Punisher: War Zone* and Titus Pollo in the HBO series *Rome*. He was a reliably stoic presence in genre films and his artistry will be missed.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsiDQ.png

Comment: I will admit that when my wife first brought up his death, I had him confused with Ray Stevens, the comedic singer and music writer. Who is still alive.